# Нужно запустить один html элемент за другим. Типа ротатор рекламы. Методом замены классов

Tags: javascript, dom

По условиям задачи, есть такой код:

Нужно методом добавления и убирания классов создать эффект ротации содержимого.

```js
"use strict";

const getAllRotationsClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".rotator__span");

const rotation = function() {
  getAllRotationsClasses.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem.classList.contains("rotator__span")) {
      elem.classList.toggle("rotator__span__active");
    }
  });
}

setInterval(rotation, 1000)
```

```css
.rotator__span {
  display: none;
}

.rotator__span__active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Я
    <span class="rotation">
                <span class="rotator_span rotator__span_active">учу JS</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">краб</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">покорю этот мир</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">не сдамся</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">упрямый</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">добьюсь своей цели</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

И этот код выбирает все не активированные, выводит их на экран в строку и убирает, а мне надо одну за другой. Как это реализовать? Объясните, пожалуйста крабу))

Comment: `elem.classList.contains("rotator__span")` какая бессмысленная проверка.. Элемент 1000% будет содержать данный класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например так:

```js
"use strict";

const getAllRotationsClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".rotation span");
let count = 1;

const rotation = function() {

  getAllRotationsClasses.forEach(function(elem, index) {
    elem.classList.toggle("rotator__span", count !== index);
  });

  count++;
  if (count >= getAllRotationsClasses.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(rotation, 1000);
```

```css
.rotator__span {
  display: none;
}

.rotator__span__active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Я
    <span class="rotation">
                <span class="">учу JS</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">краб</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">покорю этот мир</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">не сдамся</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">упрямый</span>
    <span class="rotator__span">добьюсь своей цели</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Все проверил. Код работает. Завтра буду досконально разбираться, как это работает. Не знал, что foreach может два аргумента получать) век живи - век учись) Получается, что класс 'active' и не понадобился.

Comment: @Jean-Clauds, вы можете сократить весь код внутри forEach callback-функции до `elem.classList.toggle("rotator__span", count == index)`

Comment: @Pacemaker, к вашему удивлению, там есть еще и третий, в котором находится исходный массив.

Comment: да, я уже обратил внимание, что есть и третий.

Comment: @OliverPatterson нет, не получается твоей строкой сократить код.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, обоснуйте

Comment: @OliverPatterson чёй-то я должен обосновывать? не работает с твоей строкой, так понятнее?

Comment: @OliverPatterson ты неправильно понимаешь второй аргумент функции toggle(). но если поставить `!==` то будет работать.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я то правильно понимаю, но вот наше инвертированное условие только сейчас вспомнил.